# Which maven packaging value to use for a pure documentation project?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-site-plugin, asciidoc

I've got a multimodule Maven project, one of which is a documentation project, where I'm producing reference guides for using the other modules.  I'm trying to stick to The Maven Way by using Maven's site plugin along with asciidoctor-maven-plugin.

Question is, which value should I use for the `<packaging>` element in my pom?  It's not really a jar or any of the other built-in types.  Googling for that answer leads me nowhere & everywhere... :(

Note that maven builds the site ok without specifying `<packaging>` (taking default of `jar`), but I get the warning

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ foundation-docs ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
...
```

I'd like to not get this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the packaging `pom` for the documentation projects. This packaging type will not create any JAR. See more information about the [lifecycle binding for `pom`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings).

Comment: Thanks, @LaurentG.  That worked fine.  Never thought of it.  :)